# Enabling Angular 9 Ivy throws errors

Tags: angular, npm, ivy, angular9, renderer

I have updated my app to Angular 9. I am able to run the app when I disable ivy. But when I enable ivy getting error `error NG6002:`

Error logs -

```
32 export class FooterModule { }
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/app/core/ncpapp.core.module.ts:30:14 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of 
ScreenEditorModule, but itself has errors

30 export class CoreModule {
            ~~~~~~~~~~
src/app/core/ncp-forms/ncp.forms.module.ts:19:14 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of 
ScreenEditorModule, but itself has errors

19 export class NCPFormModule { }
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/ngx-jsoneditor/jsoneditor.module.d.ts:[93m5:22 - error NG6002: Appears in the 
NgModule.imports of ScreenEditorModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.

This likely means that the library (ngx-jsoneditor) which declares JSONEditorModule has not been 
processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the 
library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if 
the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.
```

I tried to uninstall the library `ngx-jsoneditor` and reinstall again, but still getting same issue.

I did `npm cache clean --force` and did `npm install` , but the result is same.

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

install the newer version of ngx-jsoneditor that is compatible with ivy.